# Gradle build is much longer when 4g modem is connected to the PC

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

AS version 2.1.3, Gradle 2.14.1.

Without 4g modem Gradle works fast and usually takes 4-6 seconds to build the project, but with the modem (or smartphone connected via USB) it takes much longer, about 2 minutes. How to fix this?

I couldn't find any similar questions, so I'm asking here. 
I would appreciate any help.

**Update**.

This task takes most of the time: Gradle build using tasks: [:desktop:assemble, :core:assemble]

**Update**.

if I pull out the modem when Gradle's building a project, it instantly stops "thinking" and starts a program.

Comment: Looks like some connection attemts run into a time-out. Do you access repositories that are behind a firewall that my block you?

Comment: I don't really know how to check that :D But I haven't chanched anything particular in Gradle. Tried to set offline work mode, but it didn't help.